# $form_state['values'] empty in form _submit hook

Tags: forms

I have an issue with a form I built in a custom module using `drupal_get_form()` on a menu callback.

My form callback function is `_foo_form($form, $form_state)` and my submit function `_foo_form_submit($form, $form_state)`.

When I submit the form, `$form_state['values']` contains the value in the form callback, but in the submission handler `$form_state['values']` is empty.

Here is my module code:

```
function configurator_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['node/%/configurator/items'] = array(
    'title' => 'Steps & items',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('_configurator_node_edit_item', 'list', 1, ''),
    'access arguments' => array('administrer configurator'),
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
}

function _configurator_node_edit_item($form_state, $op, $nid, $iid) {
  $form = array();
  $form['nid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $nid
  );
  $form['title'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Step label',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#value' => '',
    '#size' => 30
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Save',
  );

  return $form;
}

function _configurator_node_edit_item_submit($form, $form_state) {
  dpm($form_state['values']); // devel function to print variable in drupal messages
  // returns an empty array
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Add your form's code (and submit's too) to your question, would be easier to investigate.

Comment: I just copied a few pieces of my code and forgot the submit button. It don't have any other field that the one listed above. I get to the _submit handler, the function returns my `dpm()` test. The `$form_state['values']` should contain the results but it remains empty...

Comment: Would it be easier to create a new callback function and include `drupal_get_form()` within that function? Seems like passing values would be simpler.

Comment: Actually I started by having a regular menu callback that was including a `drupal_get_form()`. When i found i can pass several values from the drupal_get_form to the callback i choose to simplify my code. I've built many forms with Drupal API and this is the first time I cannot get it working. I'll try my module in a different drupal install, and if it still doesn't work i guess i'll rewrite it from scratch...

Comment: How would you pass arguments to your form callback ? I need to pass some arguments from the form to the submit and don't want to do it using the URL. I've been reading Forms API documentation as well as `drupal_get_form` code and documentation. `$args = func_get_args();` is used in `drupal_get_form()` to pass arguments from a function to another. Nevertheless, i'm not really sure that Drupal doesn't rewrite or reset some of my variables...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change property '#value' to '#default_value'.